# What is wrong with web7 when i try to pass the variable to a cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, undefined

Sorry to give you so much code to look at but i cannot find the problem with my code and i am getting very tired. Google chrome tells me web7:43 is undefined at checkTime:10. What i a trying to do is save user entered variables in cookies to be used later in the checkTime function. Please tell me if you need more details.

```js
            
                var url;
                var url2;
                var url3;
                var url4;
                var url5;
                var url6;
                var url7;
                var url8;
            
                function change()
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var url = document.getElementById('first').value;
                    var url2 = document.getElementById('second').value;
                    var url3 = document.getElementById('advisory').value;
                    var url4 = document.getElementById('third').value;
                    var url5 = document.getElementById('fourth').value;
                    var url6 = document.getElementById('fifth').value;
                    var url7 = document.getElementById('sixth').value;
                    var url8 = document.getElementById('seventh').value;
                    
                    setCookie();
                }
                
                var web;
                var web2;
                var web3;
                var web4;
                var web5;
                var web6;
                var web7;
                var web8;
                
                function setCookie()
                {
                    web = ""document.cookie = "firstUrl="+url+"; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC""
                    web2 = ""document.cookie = "firstUrl="+url2+"; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC""
                    web3 = ""document.cookie = "firstUrl="+url3+"; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC""
                    web4 = ""document.cookie = "firstUrl="+url4+"; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC""
                    web5 = ""document.cookie = "firstUrl="+url5+"; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC""
                    web6 = ""document.cookie = "firstUrl="+url6+"; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC""
                    web7 = ""document.cookie = "firstUrl="+url7+"; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC""
                    web8 = ""document.cookie = "firstUrl="+url8+"; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC""
                }
                
                function checkTime()
                {
                    if((hours == 7) && (minutes >= 45))
                    {
                        window.open(web);
                    }
                    else if((hours == 8) && (minutes >= 48))
                    {
                        window.open(web2);
                    }
                    else if(((hours == 9) && (minutes >= 31)) || ((hours == 10) && (minutes < 5)))
                    {
                        window.open(web3);
                    }
                    else if((hours == 10) && (minutes >= 5) && (minutes < 58))
                    {
                        window.open(web4);
                    }
                    else if((hours == 10) && (minutes >= 58) || ((hours == 11) && (minutes < 44)))
                    {
                        window.open(web5);
                    }
                    else if(((hours == 11) && (minutes >= 44)) || ((hours == 12) && (minutes < 21)))
                    {
                        window.open("lunch.html");
                    }
                    else if(((hours == 12) && (minutes >= 21)) || ((hours == 13) && (minutes < 14)))
                    {
                        window.open(web6);
                    }
                    else if(((hours == 13) && (minutes >= 14)) || ((hours == 14) && (minutes < 7)))
                    {
                        window.open(web7);
                    }
                    else if(((hours == 14) && (minutes >= 7)) || ((hours == 15) && (minutes < 56)))
                    {
                        window.open(web8);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        window.open("done.html");
                    }
                }
                
                console.log(web);
```

```html
    <head>
        <script>
            var date = new Date();
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var minutes = date.getMinutes();
            
            checkTime();
            function checkTime()
            {
                if((hours == 7) && (minutes >= 45))
                {
                    window.open(web);
                }
                else if((hours == 8) && (minutes >= 48))
                {
                    window.open(web2);
                }
                else if(((hours == 9) && (minutes >= 31)) || ((hours == 10) && (minutes < 5)))
                {
                    window.open(web3);
                }
                else if((hours == 10) && (minutes >= 5) && (minutes < 58))
                {
                    window.open(web4);
                }
                else if((hours == 10) && (minutes >= 58) || ((hours == 11) && (minutes < 44)))
                {
                    window.open(web5);
                }
                else if(((hours == 11) && (minutes >= 44)) || ((hours == 12) && (minutes < 21)))
                {
                    window.open("lunch.html");
                }
                else if(((hours == 12) && (minutes >= 21)) || ((hours == 13) && (minutes < 14)))
                {
                    window.open(web6);
                }
                else if(((hours == 13) && (minutes >= 14)) || ((hours == 14) && (minutes < 7)))
                {
                    window.open(web7);
                }
                else if(((hours == 14) && (minutes >= 7)) || ((hours == 15) && (minutes < 56)))
                {
                    window.open(web8);
                }
                else
                {
                    window.open("done.html");
                }
            }   
        </script>
    </head>

        <div id="one">
            <form id="button">
                <input id="button" type="submit" value=" ">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <p style="font-size: 13px; color: white;">Copy/paste whole urls (https://www.whatever.com) for your classes</p>
            <form id="urls" onsubmit="change()">
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Period" id="first"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
            </form>
            
            <form id="urls2" onsubmit="change()">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Second Period" id="second"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
            </form>
            
            <form id="urls3" onsubmit="change()">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Advisory" id="advisory"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
            </form>
            
            <form id="urls4" onsubmit="change()">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Third Period" id="third"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
            </form>
            
            <form id="urls5" onsubmit="change()">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Fourth Period" id="fourth"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
            </form>
            
            <form id="urls6" onsubmit="change()">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Fifth Period" id="fifth"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
            </form>
            
            <form id="urls7" onsubmit="change()">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Sixth Period" id="sixth"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
            </form>
            
            <form id="urls8" onsubmit="change()">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Seventh Period" id="seventh"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
            </form>
```

Comment: if you are going to show this much code at least make it a snippet

Comment: could you explain this ?! why are you using double quotes twice at the start and the end of your line? `web = ""document.cookie = "firstUrl="+url+"; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC""`

Comment: There are several mistakes not only in syntax but also in the logic. First try to explain clearly what the code should do and then what is the problem. As I understood when the user open the page it should take the url from cookie and open the particular page. But you are missing the part that the cookie can be undefined, at least on first visit. Also you have defined the function `checkTime()` twice, there are mistakes in function `setCookie()` and so on

Comment: i used double quotes so document.cookie would not be a string, sorry if thats wrong its just how i was shown t do it. and as for the cookie syntax. i declared checktime twice because i thought that it needed to be in the body with the elements being used by it and in head because it was being used there too. it was an attempt to fix the problem and i should have removed it before asking for help, i am sorry. i have not slept in days

Answer (score 0):

3 problems with your code:

1. you declare url - url8 as global and then in your change function you declare them again.
2. your syntax for setting the cookies is wrong.  I fixed the first one.
3. you have no value defined on your elements

```js
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();

checkTime();

function checkTime() {
  if ((hours == 7) && (minutes >= 45)) {
    window.open(web);
  } else if ((hours == 8) && (minutes >= 48)) {
    window.open(web2);
  } else if (((hours == 9) && (minutes >= 31)) || ((hours == 10) && (minutes < 5))) {
    window.open(web3);
  } else if ((hours == 10) && (minutes >= 5) && (minutes < 58)) {
    window.open(web4);
  } else if ((hours == 10) && (minutes >= 58) || ((hours == 11) && (minutes < 44))) {
    window.open(web5);
  } else if (((hours == 11) && (minutes >= 44)) || ((hours == 12) && (minutes < 21))) {
    window.open("lunch.html");
  } else if (((hours == 12) && (minutes >= 21)) || ((hours == 13) && (minutes < 14))) {
    window.open(web6);
  } else if (((hours == 13) && (minutes >= 14)) || ((hours == 14) && (minutes < 7))) {
    window.open(web7);
  } else if (((hours == 14) && (minutes >= 7)) || ((hours == 15) && (minutes < 56))) {
    window.open(web8);
  } else {
    window.open("done.html");
  }
}



      var url;
      var url2;
      var url3;
      var url4;
      var url5;
      var url6;
      var url7;
      var url8;

      function change() {
        event.preventDefault();
         url = document.getElementById('first').value;
         console.log('change',url)
         url2 = document.getElementById('second').value;
         url3 = document.getElementById('advisory').value;
         url4 = document.getElementById('third').value;
         url5 = document.getElementById('fourth').value;
         url6 = document.getElementById('fifth').value;
         url7 = document.getElementById('sixth').value;
         url8 = document.getElementById('seventh').value;

        setCookie();
      }

      var web;
      var web2;
      var web3;
      var web4;
      var web5;
      var web6;
      var web7;
      var web8;
      
      //document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

      function setCookie() {
        web = ""
        console.log("\"firstUrl= "+ url + "; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC\"  "  )
        document.cookie = "\"firstUrl= "+ url + "; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC\"  "    
       
    /*
    
    web2 = ""
        document.cookie = "firstUrl=" + url2 + "; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC"
        "
        web3 = ""
        document.cookie = "firstUrl=" + url3 + "; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC"
        "
        web4 = ""
        document.cookie = "firstUrl=" + url4 + "; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC"
        "
        web5 = ""
        document.cookie = "firstUrl=" + url5 + "; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC"
        "
        web6 = ""
        document.cookie = "firstUrl=" + url6 + "; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC"
        "
        web7 = ""
        document.cookie = "firstUrl=" + url7 + "; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC"
        "
        web8 = ""
        document.cookie = "firstUrl=" + url8 + "; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC"
        " */
      }

      function checkTime() {
        if ((hours == 7) && (minutes >= 45)) {
          window.open(web);
        } else if ((hours == 8) && (minutes >= 48)) {
          window.open(web2);
        } else if (((hours == 9) && (minutes >= 31)) || ((hours == 10) && (minutes < 5))) {
          window.open(web3);
        } else if ((hours == 10) && (minutes >= 5) && (minutes < 58)) {
          window.open(web4);
        } else if ((hours == 10) && (minutes >= 58) || ((hours == 11) && (minutes < 44))) {
          window.open(web5);
        } else if (((hours == 11) && (minutes >= 44)) || ((hours == 12) && (minutes < 21))) {
          window.open("lunch.html");
        } else if (((hours == 12) && (minutes >= 21)) || ((hours == 13) && (minutes < 14))) {
          window.open(web6);
        } else if (((hours == 13) && (minutes >= 14)) || ((hours == 14) && (minutes < 7))) {
          window.open(web7);
        } else if (((hours == 14) && (minutes >= 7)) || ((hours == 15) && (minutes < 56))) {
          window.open(web8);
        } else {
          window.open("done.html");
        }
      }

      console.log(web);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">
    <form id="button">
      <input id="button" type="submit" value=" ">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p style="font-size: 13px; color: white;">Copy/paste whole urls (https://www.whatever.com) for your classes</p>
    <form id="urls" onsubmit="change()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Period" id="first" value='https://stackoverflow.com'> <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>

    <form id="urls2" onsubmit="change()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Second Period" id="second"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>

    <form id="urls3" onsubmit="change()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Advisory" id="advisory"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>

    <form id="urls4" onsubmit="change()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Third Period" id="third"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>

    <form id="urls5" onsubmit="change()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Fourth Period" id="fourth"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>

    <form id="urls6" onsubmit="change()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Fifth Period" id="fifth"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>

    <form id="urls7" onsubmit="change()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Sixth Period" id="sixth"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>

    <form id="urls8" onsubmit="change()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Seventh Period" id="seventh"> <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i just tried your code an it did not work but thank you for taking time to help.

Comment: seems to work fine in the snippet.  What error are you getting